# Formatting a date with Moment Tz

Tags: ios, datetime, ionic-framework, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm struggling with formatting a date to insert into a calendar. I'm working on an Ionic project and I'm attempting to leverage moment.js timezones. The data is being passed into the application in several pieces. I am receiving a `millisecond` date time stamp, a 24-hour string for time and a string of the timezone. The date does not contain the time. What I want to achieve is creating a date object from these pieces and then converting the date into the user's local timezone to add it to their device calendar.

**example of data passed to app**

```
The date of the event: August 14, 2018 17:00    
time = 17:00
date = 1534204800
timezone = AEDT
```

The destination timezone is based on the user's location.

```
    let timeFormatter = new Date();
    timeFormatter.setMilliseconds(date);
    let momentHrMin = moment(timeFormatter.toDateString() + " " + time);

    //WP sever is on GMT get the day, month and yr
    let momentTZDate = momentTz.unix(date);
    momentTZDate.tz('GMT');
    let day = momentTZDate.days();
    let month = momentTZDate.month();
    let yr = momentTZDate.year();

    //set the correct timezone on the ecpoh/unix DATE with momentTz.
    momentTZDate.tz(this.eventDetails.eventDetail.timezoneOffset);

    // Lastly set the date so the timezone conversions are correct
    momentTZDate.set(
      {
        day: day,
        month: month,
        year: yr,
        hour: momentHrMin.hour(),
        minute: momentHrMin.minute(),
        second: 0,
        millisecond: 0
      }
    );
```

Comment: So what's going wrong? You've explained what you want to achieve, but we're lacking a description of the current issue you're facing

Comment: The issue I was facing was I kept getting the wrong timezone. After a few hours of digging through documentation yesterday, I found the issue. `AEDT` could represent multiple timezones (American Eastern Standard, Australian Eastern Standard, etc) so `moment.tz` doesn't accept this value. I just needed to use moment's timezone `Australia/Brisbane`

Comment: you should write it as the answer instead of a comment. Might be useful for others in future. You can also attract upvotes.

Comment: @ADyson great minds think alike, I was typing up an answer just as you sent that. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of my struggles with the timezones. The abbreviated AEDT is not an accepted value for Moment.tz. AEDT could represent multiple timezones. For example, American Eastern, Australian Eastern, etc... Simply changing `momentTZDate.tz("AEDT");` to `momentTZDate.tz("Australia/Brisbane");` fixed my issue. Below is my `typescript` code I used to get through this issue. I won't say its the best but it works.

```
 private getCalDate(date:number, time: string): Date {

    // create an object in which the hours and minutes can be parse from(do to free text entry on the backend moment handles different inputs)
    let timeFormatter = new Date();
    timeFormatter.setMilliseconds(date);
    let momentHrMin = moment(timeFormatter.toDateString() + " " + time);

    //WP sever is on GMT get the day, month and yr
    let momentTZDate = momentTz.unix(date);
    momentTZDate.tz('GMT');
    let day = momentTZDate.days();
    let month = momentTZDate.month();
    let yr = momentTZDate.year();

    //set the correct timezone on the ecpoh/unix DATE with momentTz.
    momentTZDate.tz("Australia/Brisbane");

    // Lastly set the date so the timezone conversions are correct
    momentTZDate.set(
      {
        day: day,
        month: month,
        year: yr,
        hour: momentHrMin.hour(),
        minute: momentHrMin.minute(),
        second: 0,
        millisecond: 0
      }
    );

    return momentTZDate.toDate();
}
```